# yticks have unexpectedly variable font size

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I am modifying the yticks font size of a figure but **not all yticks are of the same font size**. The last two yticks `0.8` and `0.6` are greater than the others.

```
def mm_to_inch(value):
    return value/25.4

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = "Arial"
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = "sans-serif"
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 112
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(mm_to_inch(size), mm_to_inch(size/2)))

df = pd.read_csv('testing_errors_prob.csv')
df = df.drop(['precision', 'recall', 'TP', 'FP', 'TN', 'FN'], axis=1)
df = df.sort_values(by=['accuracy'], ascending=False)
df = df.replace({'Gaussian Nb': 'Gaussian\nNb', 'Extra Trees': 'Extra\nTrees', 'Random Forest': 'Random\nForest',
                     'Decision Tree': 'Decision\nTree', 'Gradient Boost': 'Gradient\nBoost', 'Linear SVC': 'Linear\nSVC',
                     'Ada Boost': 'Ada\nBoost', 'Bernouli Nb': 'Bernouli\nNb'})
df.plot.bar(x='model', ax=ax1, color=['#093145', '#107896', '#829356'], width=0.8)
plt.tight_layout()

# plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha="right", fontsize=6)
# plt.yticks(fontsize=6)
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha="right", fontsize=6)
plt.yticks(fontsize=6)
plt.legend(["Accuracy", "F1", "AUC ROC"], fontsize="xx-large", prop={'size': 5})

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.2)
plt.xlabel('')

plt.savefig('results_updateddd_{}.png'.format(size))
plt.savefig('results_updateddd_{}.pdf'.format(size))
plt.close()
```

The figure looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I read your question. but I can't understand. Do you want to plot with the y-axis by different sizes?

Comment: @user1740577 I am actually referring to the yticks. If you realize they are of different font sizes(the last two yticks 0.8 and 0.6 they are bigger than the others) and I'm trying to figure out why ?

Comment: you want y-axises have same size and don't have different size?

Comment: @user1740577 yes they must all have the same size because I specified ```plt.yticks(fontsize=6)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `subplots_adjust` causes new `yticks` to appear when it alters the subplot layout:

- **`yticks(fontsize=6)`** only targets existing ticks, so it will not affect any future ticks that show up (e.g., new ticks that appear after `subplots_adjust`)
- **`tick_params(labelsize=6)`** sets the tick size for the whole `Axes`, so even when new ticks show up, they automatically inherit this tick size just by being part of the `Axes`

So if you want to use the `yticks(fontsize=6)` method, make sure to call it last:

```
...
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.2)
plt.yticks(fontsize=6)
...
```

| `fontsize` -> `subplots_adjust` | `subplots_adjust` -> `fontsize` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: fontsize first] | [image: subplots_adjust first] |

Answer (score 2):

I am still not sure why, but the bug was from `plt.yticks(fontsize=6)`. I removed it and replaced it with

```
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=6)
```

Comment: Yep this also works. I added an explanation for the "why" and also how to fix the `yticks(fontsize=6)` method.